# Перевести строки разбитые "\n" в массив

Tags: javascript

Есть вопрос, полный 0 в JavaScript. Есть данные передаваемые от сервера в виде строк разбитых на "\n". Подскажите как их разбить на массив в самом javascript'е, что бы вывести в виде таблицы?

---

[image: получаемые данные]
[image: JavaScript]

Вот в таком виде получаю данные с сервера.

Как работать с этим массивом, не пойму.

Comment: Приведите пример ответа сервера. Пока из него может получиться разве что строчка таблицы.

Comment: Проблема в твоем коде в том, что ты не сохраняешь результат вызова split. А в функцию myFunction передаешь обычную строку, у которой нет метода forEach, что интересно, внутри коллбэка forEach ты сохраняешь результат `stringData.stplit`, почему не делаешь то же самое снаружи?

Comment: Минус за оформление вопроса: нужно отредактировать ВОПРОС, а не добавлять детали ОТВЕТАМИ. Кроме того, вставка кода КАРТИНКАМИ -- это крайне плохая практика, была бы возможность -- ещё минус поставил.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь стало понятно, работает. P.S. править не мог, ну не было у меня такой кнопки под моими сообщениями. Теперь появилась. Про вставку кода - учту, спасибо что нет возможности еще больше поставить минусов, особенно с учетом что кроме претензии по оформлению полезной информации от А.К. не поступало.

Comment: Пожалуйста, всегда размещайте код в виде текста, а не картинкой. Поисковики пока не научились индексировать код в картинках и в ближайшее время не будут. А ещё из картинки крайне сложно скопировать код в среду разработки, чтобы его проверить или отредактировать.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "a\nb\nc"
str.split("\n") // => массив ["a","b","c"]
```